# Unity - Use concrete type depending on user choice

Tags: unity-container

I have a small app (Win Forms) where I have two different repositories (SQL Server and Redis) both implementing a interface IFilterRepo.
I also have a service class that depends on the IFilterRepo. The client (the Win Form) call the service to access filter data.

I want the client to have two radio buttons where a user can choose which repo to use. And here comes my dilemma. How should I tell the service which concrete class to instantiate as IFilterRepo? I mean, ALL Unity registrations and references to it shall be done in the composition root. Is that "rule" really possible in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common question, and the answer is generally to use an Abstract Factory.

Here is a good article on the subject (I link this all the time, but I didn't write it):

http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory/

As noted in the article, you can make the factory part of the composition root, so that calling container.Resolve() inside the factory doesn't violate that rule.

**Edit**

You would register different implementations of the service using a name (string):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648211.aspx

```
myContainer.RegisterType<IMyService, CustomerService>("Customers");
```

And then your factory would resolve by that name:

```
public IFilterRepo Create(string myName)
{
   return myContainer.Resolve<IFilterRepo>(myName);
}
```

**Edit 2**

The question you asked in your last comment is a bit much to answer here, but in brief: your factory itself would implement an interface, and would be resolved and registered via the container.

As a general matter, I would not recommend accessing a repository directly from the code behind--I would at least look at having a layered architecture (or better, an [Onion](http://www.develop.com/onionarchitecture) architecture, which works very well with DI).

Finally, I have not done WinForms development in years, but I don't think it fits perfectly with using a container/Composition Root, since you don't have full control over the lifecycle of your objects (you can't inject services into your form constructors).  The same is true of ASP.Net Webforms.  So you may have to use property injection for your factory and other services needed in your form, or just resolve the factory directly via calling a static instance of the container (container.Resolve()).  This is imperfect, and goes against the idea of having a Composition Root, and more toward service location.

You might google keywords "Unity WinForms" and/or "[OtherDIFramework] Winforms" to get some ideas of how to structure your code.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand how to specify the repo to use. I mean, when the user selects a radio button I need to choose an implementation. How? Do you mean I should have two factories (one for each implementation of the rep interface)? A small code example of the "radiobutton_changed()" would be very helpful :)

Comment: Sorry, it was not totally clear after all. From the link about factory you provided I can see that his ContainerFactory class has no static properties. In my radiobutton_changed() method I guess I need to do a "var factory = new ContainerFactory()". Shouldn't the factory be crested in the composition root? If so, how do I access that factory object in radiobutton_changed()?

Comment: I can inject into the form constructor from main method. So, should I inject the factory in the constructor? I thought only service dependencies should be injected.

Comment: I will not call the repository from code behind, I will call a service which in turn call the repository. But I need a way to tell the service which repo to use. My thought here is to let Unity resolve the repo in the service constructor. That's where the factory comes into play I guess.

Comment: Yes, you should inject the factory into the constructor.  The factory IS a service--it is a service that provides the correct implementation of your repo.  It's not a "service" by the SOA definition; it's a service by the DI definition.

Comment: Thanks Phil. Now I understand, I promise :)